# None as a output to my code. I wanted a calculated output from my code. Is it wrong to use logical statement after if else?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a project and my code is returning none as output

I have tried indenting and unindenting the return line but it din't help. Is it wrong if I put the formula just after the if else statement?

```
def cost_of_ground_shipping(weight):
  #weight = float(weight)

  if(weight<=2.0):
    cost = (weight * 1.5) + 20.00
    return cost
  elif(weight>2.0) and (weight<=6.0):
    cost = (weight * 3.00) + 20.00
    return cost
  elif(weight>6.0) and (weight>=10.0):
    cost = (weight * 4.00) + 20.00
    return cost
  elif(weight>10.0):
    cost = (weight * 4.75) + 20.00
    return cost
print(cost_of_ground_shipping(8.4))
```

I expected the result 53.60

Comment: The third condition should be `elif(weight>6.0) and (weight<=10.0):`, also a better approach is to put `return cost` at the end of the function

Comment: `8.4` does not satisfy any of the conditions, hence the function implicitly returns `None`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh or `elif 6.0 < weight <= 10.0 `

Comment: In python you can write range checks like `6.0 < weight <= 10.0`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: `weight >= 10.0` should be `weight <= 10.0`. Since the function never reached a `return` statement, it implicitly returned `None`.

As well, we can improve the code by factoring out the calculation and `return` statement (see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), removing unnecessary parens, using Python's clearer range check syntax (`x < y <= z`), and using descriptive variable names:

```
def cost_of_ground_shipping(weight):
  base = 20.0
  if weight <= 2.0:
    multiplier = 1.5
  elif 2.0 < weight <= 6.0:
    multiplier = 3.0
  elif 6.0 < weight <= 10.0:
    multiplier = 4.0
  elif 10.0 < weight:
    multiplier = 4.75
  return weight * multiplier + base

print(cost_of_ground_shipping(8.4))  # -> 53.6
```

If you had written the code like this but still had the typo, the `return` line would have thrown an error: `NameError: name 'multiplier' is not defined`, which would be your first hint for starting debugging.